# Using Filter to return content within class and the class itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

Filter behaves as expected, it returns multiple divs with a class of post. However, it only returns the content within the div

```
<h1></h1>
```

and not

```
<div class="post"><h1></h1></div>
```

Would it be possible to get this sort of output?

I.e. this sort of output

```
<div class="post"><h1></h1></div>
```

Here's the code:

```
$(result).filter('.post').each(function(i, currentElement) {
    var htmlOfSinglePost = $(this).html();
    var p = $(htmlOfSinglePost).attr("data-post-id");
    console.log(p);
});
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour], have a look around, and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) What does your HTML look like? Please update your question with a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, ideally a **runnable** one using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button; [here's how to do one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-do-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do-tha)).

Comment: When you were asking your question, there was a big orange **How to Format** box to the right of the text area with useful information in it. There was also an entire toolbar of formatting aids. And a **[?]** button giving formatting help. *And* a preview area located between the text area and the Post Your Question button (so that you'd have to scroll past it to find the button, to encourage you to look at it) showing what your post would look like when posted. Making your post clear, and demonstrating that you took the time to do so, improves your chances of getting good answers.

Comment: (I've fixed it for you this time.)

Comment: A non-jQuery solution: use `.outerHTML`

Comment: It would help if you provide a sample of your HTML, and your expected output (or intended use). You might be overcomplicating things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$(this).html();` would give you the inner HTML of the specified selector excluding the selector itself.

It you want inner html and selector element itself, you may want to use

```
$(selector)[0].outerHTML
```

here is snippet

```js
$(".post").each(function(){
console.log($(this)[0].outerHTML)
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post"><h1></h1></div>
<div class="post"><h1>This is other one</h1></div>
```

Comment: There is no need to wrap `this` into a jQuery wrapper only to unwrap it again using `[0]`. Just use `this.outerHTML` right away.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your `result` contains HTML, given some basic example HTML, within your `.each()` the `this` refers to the current HTML element (not the jQuery) object. To get the outer HTML element, you can use [**outerHTML**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/outerHTML) as seen below.

To get the `data-post-id` value from the outer content, wrap it into a jQuery wrapper to use `$(outerContent).data('postId')`.

> Just to add, the reason you cannot use `getAttribute()` on a result
>   from `outerHTML` is because `outerHTML` resturns a
>   [**DOMString**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMString)
>   and while you can take the `DOMString` and convert it into an element it
>   is faster at this point to just use jQuery `$(...outerHTML).data()` *but only because you are already using it*

```js
$('.post').each(function(i, currentElement) {
    var outerContent = this.outerHTML;
    console.log(outerContent);
    
    var p = $(outerContent).data('postId');
    console.log('postId = ',p);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="post" data-post-id="15">
  <h1>Post</h1>
</div>
<div class="post" data-post-id="57">
  <h1>Post 2</h1>
</div>
```